# How can I use dependency locking for a constraints-only Gradle `platform`?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, dependency-management, maven-bom

I have a Gradle (v6.6.1) [platform](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_platform_plugin.html) module that I publish to our internal maven repo.  It's a constraints-only platform, and intended to be used by a large number of projects in my org so that we can standardize on versions of common dependencies.

So far it's working fine: I periodically review each dependency to look for an updated release, update those versions in my `build.gradle.kts` file, bump the version number of the platform itself (major or minor, depending on the changes), and publish that new platform to the maven repo.

However, doing so is a time-consuming and manual process.  I'd much rather specify my version range constraints in `build.gradle.kts` (for example, latest patch version, or the latest minor version), and then use [dependency locking](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_locking.html) to update the recommended version to for each dependency to a new specific version.

The problem is, Gradle seems to forbid this.  Even when I use the following, it will only produce an empty `api.lockfile`:

```
dependencyLocking {
    lockAllConfigurations()
}
task("resolveAndLockAll") {
    doFirst {
        require(gradle.startParameter.isWriteDependencyLocks,
                { "You must specify `--write-locks` to update the dependency version lock" })
        configurations["api"].setCanBeResolved(true) // `api` not resolvable by default
    }
    doLast {
        configurations.forEach {
            println("Reviewing configuration ${it}...")
            if (it.isCanBeResolved && it.name != "archives" && it.name != "default") {
                it.resolve()
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    constraints {
        api("com.google.guava:guava:${ property("guavaVersion") }")
        api("com.google.inject:guice:${ property("guiceVersion") }")
        ... // many more
    }
}
```

I think I understand the logic behind this: my platform only publishes constraints (not dependencies) so dependency locking doesn't apply.  However, I want to specify exact constraints, allowing the consuming projects to jump from release to release of my platform project with exact versions recommended to them.

I also understand that those consuming projects can use dependency locking to get reproducible builds (and they do), but again, I want to specify exact constraints so that everyone on version, say, 17.4 of my platform is using *exactly* the same dependencies, and they can coordinate on issues they encounter.

#### Workaround(s)

The best idea I've got is to have a second, private module that defines the same set of dependencies (as actual dependencies) but with broader version ranges (e.g. `[1.1, 2.0)` instead of `1.4.3`).  I can use that module to generate a lock file, and then write a script that will update the `platform`'s `build.gradle.kts` file with the newly-resolved specific dependency versions.